# App using Cortana is not appearing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uwp, cortana

I'm working on a demo app which integrates Cortana functionality in Windows 10.

I had it working at first, but when I would say the name of the app, it appeared to be installed twice. Example:

*Cortana is activated and listening*

*"Launch Demo App"*

The app launcher pops up and asks something along the lines of "Which one would you like to run?" and shows the app twice.

I right-**click -> Uninstal**l both of them.

I've now tried launching the app from visual studio by hitting **Deploy -> Local Machine,** and then stating the same voice command, and nothing pops up. It simply launches Cortana with the day's information.

**Steps taken**

I went back to Visual Studio and created some more demo apps, and they appear as new apps in my Start Menu, but this demo app never appears. I even tried creating it from scratch again.

I tried clearing the voice commands files from Cortana:

In Explorer go to *%localappdata%*
 
From there go to *Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw…\LocalStat*e

- Rename VoiceCommands.0409.cfg to VoiceCommands.0409.cfg.old
- Rename VoiceCommands.Components.cfg to VoiceCommands.0409.cfg.old

Power Shell:

**Get-process searchui | kill**
 
This wipes all voice commands in Cortana.

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: Which build of windows 10 are you using? Is this a Insiders fast-ring build? You should be able to clean this up if you uninstall both of them, and then try to use the voice commands you had registered. Once Cortana recognizes a command it no longer has an associated app for, it'll clean up. This behavior isn't ideal, and will improve down the line, but for now, this should help you get back into a good place.

Comment: >I've now tried launching the app from visual studio by hitting Deploy -> Local Machine, and then stating the same voice command, and nothing pops up.
Have you started the App once? And have you checked if the Voice Commands installed? Cortana: "What can I say?" is the App showing up?

Comment: "What can I say" is clever. I didn't notice that before. 

It now shows SpeechRecognition as appearing twice, as well as another app I created call SpeechRecognition1. When I try to say "Hey Cortana, SpeechRecognition, Launch" It jut opens Cortana. 

Same thing if I say "Hands on Labs, launch", which is the name of this demo and what I have listed in the commands xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:** For some reason this was resolved the next day. No idea.

**UPDATE:** This didn't resolve it. To make sure this was the solution, I uninstalled it again, then tried repeating these steps, and I still cannot launch the app.

As silly as it sounds, I needed to restart my machine after uninstalling the app.

Once I did the steps above, followed by restarting the machine, I could then run the again again from Visual Studio, which installed it again, and appeared in my menu.